# Flutter App Crashes when we call JitsiMeet.closeMeeting()

Tags: android, flutter, jitsi-meet

I have developed a FLUTTER APPLICATION and I have implemented JITSI.
**Im trying to close the meeting manually through function JitsiMeet.closeMeeting();**
When I do this APP Is CRASHING. I got below messages in the console.

Im using the version:
**jitsi_meet: ^2.0.0**

> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity.getJitsiView(JitsiMeetActivity.java:110)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity.leave(JitsiMeetActivity.java:126)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity.finish(JitsiMeetActivity.java:99)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity.onConferenceTerminated(JitsiMeetActivity.java:223)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> com.gunschu.jitsi_meet.JitsiMeetPluginActivity.onConferenceTerminated(JitsiMeetPluginActivity.kt:88)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): ... 11 more E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570):
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ListenerUtils.runListenerMethodOnUiThread(ListenerUtils.java:139)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ListenerUtils.access$000(ListenerUtils.java:35)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ListenerUtils$1.run(ListenerUtils.java:114)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570):
> at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ListenerUtils.runListenerMethodOnUiThread(ListenerUtils.java:135)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): ... 9 more E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetView
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetFragment.getJitsiView()' on a null object
> reference E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity.getJitsiView(JitsiMeetActivity.java:110)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity.leave(JitsiMeetActivity.java:126)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity.finish(JitsiMeetActivity.java:99)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity.onConferenceTerminated(JitsiMeetActivity.java:223)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): at
> com.gunschu.jitsi_meet.JitsiMeetPluginActivity.onConferenceTerminated(JitsiMeetPluginActivity.kt:88)
> E/JitsiMeetSDK(30570): ... 11 more I/Process (30570): Sending signal.
> PID: 30570 SIG: 9 Lost connection to device.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: Still no, one guy has found the solution and sent them, but still they didnt update